# AngularJS routing to static file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I have a simple `angularjs` app, with `ngRoute` module for routing in `html5Mode`.
How can I have a link to some static file on my page, and not to have it intercepted by angular routing module?

Here's the example:

HTML:

```
    <head>
        <base href='/'></base>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="crudApp">

    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/user">User</a>
    <a href="/users.html">users.html</a>

    <div ng-view></div>
```

JS routing:

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/home/homeView.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'

            })
            .when('/user', {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/user/userView.html',
                controller: 'UserController'

            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
```

When I click on *User* link I get routed to `localhost:8080/user`, and my controller and template work fine. When I click on *users.html* link I get routed to home, but I want to invoke a static `home.html` page.

Comment: try without the slash (or path to where ever your static file is ...) if you just want direct html... <a href="users.html">users.html</a>

Comment: why not create a route for home.html?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location), you have 3 options:

> #### Html link rewriting
>
> (...)
>
> In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.
>
> - Links that contain target element
>     Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
> - Absolute links that go to a different domain
>     Example: `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
> - Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path
>     Example: `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

What you might be looking for is the first example:

```
<a href="/users.html" target="_self">users.html</a>
```